# MinGW make on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, mingw

I have MinGW installed on my Windows 8.1 machine, and I'm using it to develop C++ code that can be ported to Unix/Linux systems in lieu of being able to dual-boot Ubuntu or similar.

I have a generic makefile that should work for building the project, but for some reason, the `find` command on Windows is unable to find source files for the project.  I get this error:

```
File not found - *.cpp
Makefile:32: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
```

Here is the makefile I use (I adapted it from [this](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/) blog, along with the basic project structure from the blog:

```
CC := g++ # This is the main compiler
# CC := clang --analyze # and comment out the linker last line for sanity
SRCDIR := src           # Directory for source code
BUILDDIR := build       # Directory containing all object files, which are removed on "make clean"
TARGET := bin/runner    # bin/runner contains the main executable for project
                    # bin/ contains all other executables in the project (such as tests)

SRCEXT := cpp           # File extension of source code

# Look for all the source files in SRCDIR with the file extension specified above
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))

# Name all object files the same root name as the source files from which they came, but add a .o extension to the end
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))

# The -g flag specifies that debugging information should be produced in the native format of the OS
CFLAGS := -g # -Wall

# Various flags for libraries that might need to be linked
LIB := -pthread -lmongoclient -L lib -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt

# Ensures that all header files (in the include/ folder) are accessible for build
INC := -I include

# Show the components that are currently being compiled/linked
# Also, this is the main procedure for make: The TARGET is built from the objects, and
# object files are built from source
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo " Linking..."
    @echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    @echo " $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

# Directives for "make clean" which cleans all object files out of the build/ folder
clean:
    @echo " Cleaning..."; 
    @echo " $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

# Tests
# tester:
    # $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test/tester.cpp $(INC) $(LIB) -o bin/tester

# Spikes
# ticket:
    # $(CC) $(CFLAGS) spikes/ticket.cpp $(INC) $(LIB) -o bin/ticket

# Destroys everything in the build/ and bin/runner/ folders. Does not clean test executables.
.PHONY: clean
```

If I open an enhanced console in the root directory of my project, and run `find src/ -name '*.cpp'`, I get the same error as above.  Running the `dir` Windows command from the root also does not find the cpp files.  However, when run from the `src` directory, `dir` can find all of my source files, while `find` cannot.  Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

The `find` command on Windows is completely different than the find `find` command on Unix. It performs a function more like `grep` on Unix.  Your makefile in general assumes a number of Unix utilities so won't work on Windows, or at least not unless you use something that provides all the Unix commands it expects. You could use Cygwin or MSYS, the later being a stripped down fork of the former. Cygwin by default creates Cygwin applications, while MSYS by default creates "native" Windows applications.

It's also possible to rewrite the makefile to use Windows commands. Something like:

```
# Look for all the source files in SRCDIR with the file extension specified above
SOURCES := $(shell dir /b /s $(SRCDIR)\*.$(SRCEXT))

...

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        @echo Linking...
        $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
        -mkdir $(BUILDDIR)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

# Directives for "make clean" which cleans all object files out of the build/ folder
clean:
        @echo Cleaning...; 
        -rmdir /s /q $(BUILDDIR) 
        -del $(TARGET)
```

An alternative to using `dir /b /s` would be to just simply list source files. Generally this is a better idea than generating the list dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue originally reported without changing  the makefile, do the following

1. Go to the folder where MinGW is installed on your system
2. Search for find.exe
3. Add the folder in which find.exe is located to system or user environment vars.
4. Don't forget to restart or close the applications to make the change effective.
5. You can manually test find command and you can see it works