# Makefile on Windows: Is there a way to force make to use the minGW `find.exe`?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm using mingw-w64 to build my program using `gcc` on windows.
In my makefile, I'm doing the following to find all source files:

```
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.c' -or -name '*.s')
```

As you can see below, the `FIND` command makes my build crash.

```
File not found - *.cpp
FIND: Parameter format not correct
# ...
```

After using `make -d` to see what's happening under the hood, I discovered that my makefile use `system32\find.exe` instead of the find provided by MinGW.

```
$ make -d
# ...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
CreateProcess(C:\WINDOWS\system32\find.exe,find ./src -name *.cpp -or -name *.c -or -name 
File not found - *.cpp
*.s,...)
# ...
```

Is there a way to force make to use the proper `find` command?
If not, how to address this portability issue?

---

**EDIT**:

It looks like I'm punished for doing fancy stuff.
As mentioned in the comments, minGW-w64 doesn't come with a `FIND` util.

My new problem is therefore to translate the following lines for windows:

```
SRC_DIRS := ./src
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.c' -or -name '*.s')
INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type d)
```

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/q/26110353/1606345?

Comment: You may try to adapt your `PATH` environment variable to use either only the MSYS binaries, or look these up first. Do that before calling `make`

Comment: It seems like mingw-w64 doesn't come with a `find.exe`. That would explain it.

Comment: Sounds like you want a more Unix-y tool chain like MSYS2.

Comment: I believe mingw-w64 is only the compiler.  It doesn't provide a full set of POSIX utilities.

Comment: [Installation instructions for MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)

Answer (score 0):

You can go several ways to bypass this.

1. Short way. Use full path: `/bin/find`
2. Hard way. Parse the output from `where find` and take the first one path without a prefix path from `WINDIR` variable. To port this to Linux - parse `which where` before `where find`.

I like the hard way:

```bash
# `which` to avoid recursion in `function find`
SHELL_FIND=`which find`

# detect `find.exe` in Windows behind `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\find.exe`
if which where >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  for path in `where find 2>/dev/null`; do
    case "$path" in
      "$WINDIR"\\*)
        ;;
      *)
        SHELL_FIND="$path"
        break
        ;;
    esac
  done
fi
```

To silently replace the `find`:

```bash
function find()
{
  "$SHELL_FIND" "$@"
}

function find.exe()
{
  "$SHELL_FIND" "$@"
}
```